# Using launch screen stops scaling (.xib)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using a .xib file as a launch screen. Everything is set to size freeform but it won't auto scale to the 4 inch screen on iPhone 5. The .xib file is extremely simple and is set to height any and width any with some text labels on it. What am I doing wrong here? How can I enable auto scaling?

Comment: When you open the xib file and use the Document Outline (opened via the small square at bottom left of view window), what are the constraints set for the various elements of the xib? I find if I set them based on distance from vertical center of the superview and the horizontal center of the superview, and pin the width and height of each element, then the xib scales no matter what screen I use.

Comment: There are not constraints besides centering a label both horizontally and vertically